# umask in Ubuntu Server 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, umask

This is on a test machine, not production. I included the following in a user's .bashrc:

```
umask 000
```

I relogged in. When I go to create a file in my home directory, say using vi test.txt, the file gets permission rw-rw-rw.

I also tried setting umask manually:

```
umask a=rwx
```

What am I doing wrong, as I need the equivalent of CHMOD 0777 or 0755 on files and directories? Again, this is a test situation, so security is of no concern at the moment.

Edit: Come to think of it, is this impossible? Since umask for files gets subtracted for 666, lowest umask is 000, therefore, CHMOD of 666 is the highest a file can get? There's no way to give files CHMOD of 755 or 777 using umask?

Comment: What output do you get for `cd /tmp ; rm -f masktest; umask 000; touch masktest ; ls -l masktest`?

Comment: -rw-rw-rw- ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a reference but I'm fairly sure that you can't set `x` as a default permission on a file.

Comment: Possibly as security measure, you do not want files to be executable by default. Since the umask also applies to directory creation which needs the execute bit for allowing users to descend into it, it makes sense for not requiring `umask 133` to prevent the execute bit from being set on files.

Comment: The umask doesn't set default permissions, it *masks* them. It's up to the code calling `open()` with `O_CREATE` to set the executable bits or not.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Yup - I would expct that to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

`umask` doesn't *set* the default permissions, it's used to modify the default mode of certain system calls, like, `open(2)` and `mkdir(2)`.

In your case, `vim` is creating the file with a mode of `0666`, which would be further modified by the umask. The default of 0022, would then create a file with a mode of 0644. The umask can't add bits, it can only *mask* them (hence the name).

As an example, executing

```
$ touch testfile
$ ls -l testfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 bob bob 0 2011-06-27 16:36 testfile
```

yet it made the following system call (notice the 0666 in the mode_t field)

```
open("testfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
```